# Purpose of `AsMemory()` applied to `byte[]` in `FileStream`

Tags: c#, memory, .net-7.0, asp.net-core-7.0

I'm revising the code and notice that I get a suggestion to use the [extension method `AsMemory(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memoryextensions.asmemory?view=net-7.0). I've never seen it before nor ha a reason to consider it. Never the less, one's either learn och obsoletes, so I got intrigued.

After reading the (rather limited) docs and (equally poor) set of blogs (honestly, [this one](https://medium.com/@norm.bryar/dictionaries-and-spans-7b72433da75d)) was the only remotely relevant I found, I decided I'm too ignorant to make a judgement call on this.

This is a sample of the code used.

```
await using FileStream input = new(path, FileMode.Open);
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
long remaining = input.Length;
int index = 0;

do
{
  int read = await input.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, Config.Chunk);
  remaining -= read;
  await using FileStream output = new(destination, FileMode.CreateNew);
  await output.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, read);
} while (remaining > 0);
input.Close();
```

What's the practical difference between those two readings from a stream? Where can I find more relevant and reliable information?

```
int read1 = await input.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, Config.Chunk);
int read2 = await input.ReadAsync(buffer.AsMemory(0, Config.Chunk));
```

I strongly hope that it has to do with performance optimization and/or thread management. However, I also hope to be handsome and funny, which was a mistake...

The same question goes for the writing operation, I guess.

```
await output.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, read);
await output.WriteAsync(buffer.AsMemory(0, read));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**None, in this case.**

The overload does exactly the same thing as your own code: it creates a `ReadOnlyMemory` from the `buffer` array.

[Source code is here:](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/bee65d373e98b6cec39abec54d2eade98b0a03c6/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/Strategies/OSFileStreamStrategy.cs#L254) (it eventually reaches a class called `FileStreamStrategy`)

```cs
public sealed override Task WriteAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>
    WriteAsync(new ReadOnlyMemory<byte>(buffer, offset, count), cancellationToken).AsTask();

public sealed override ValueTask WriteAsync(ReadOnlyMemory<byte> source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    long writeOffset = CanSeek ? Interlocked.Add(ref _filePosition, source.Length) - source.Length : -1;
    return RandomAccess.WriteAtOffsetAsync(_fileHandle, source, writeOffset, cancellationToken, this);
}
```

---

Having said that, in many cases it is useful. This is normally where you would get a `Memory` from somewhere else, for example from an unmanaged memory block, or from some kind of array pool.

Comment: This should be better documented and wider blogged about. It feels like I'm *the first guy* on it (Sort of first, of course, I'm not **that** arrogant, hehe.)

Answer (score 2):

`Memory<T>` (or more specifically, `Span<T>`, with memory basically being a "I can give you a span on demand", API, since span has very specific usage requirements) is basically a way of generalizing `T[]` to allow it to refer to any contiguous block of memory, not just arrays. treating an array as a memory won't give you much by itself; the real gain is being able to use *other memory kinds* (which might happen to be arrays, or might not) via the same API, usually without even needing to know the underlying memory store involved. In fact, I'd wager that the first thing the memory-based API is going to do is ask "is this actually an array? if so, use the other overload" - so it might actually be that you're adding a (albeit very fast) wrap+unwrap here (although at least it doesn't involve any allocations).

So: if you don't need that: don't worry about it, just use arrays and you'll be fine. If you are interested in non-array-based memory locations, then: it is great to know that you now have an API that allows that.

This is mostly useful to library and framework folks.

Comment: What exactly are those other memory types? Or contiguous memory blocks that are not arrays? AFAIK Memory<T> is literally an array together with offset and count.

Comment: @freakish your AFAIK is very very wrong. A memory T *can* be based on an array of T; however: a memory just needs to be able to provide a span - it could be based on an interior managed pointer to the innards of an object, it could be based on an unmanaged pointer to the stack, to unmanaged process memory, to a mmap-d file, to GPU memory, or anything else you can want. In the specific case of char, it could be based on a string. All sorts of weird and wonderful things are possible with memory and span.

Comment: @freakish one other important thing that is possible via spans (the important part of memory): casting between value-types (as long as they don't include references) - for example, a `byte[]` (or a `Span<byte>` more generally) can be treated as a `Span<float>`, or even a `Span<Vector<float>>` - noting that array variance does *not* allow this. This is very useful to enable SIMD against raw buffers, for example.